# htaccess 301 redirect for all versions website

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with redirecting my website to new domain. I my old domain is https://elysian-store.ir
I decided to buy the .com version in order to have google advertisment for my site (.ir is banned!!! and thought the net was free of politics)

Anyways, here is my situation:

Old website: https://elysian-store.ir
New domain: https://elysian-store.com

I want to redirect all of content old website, to the new with considration of all verieties like : 
www.elysian-store.ir or .com
http versions to https versions.

I have added all versions to google web console and tried to implement redirect codes to htaccess of my website.

I use latest version of wordpress.

If someone could put me in the right direction for 301 redirect it would be great.

I have access to website cpanel too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the directories to be appended to the redirect? If so then this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://elysian-store.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```